# How to run a method inside an object with different threads simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading

My setup is as described. What I want to accomplish is have the aMethod in each of my implemented classes to run in parallel. I have looked into using `Future`s and `Runnable` and I am unsure how to proceed with either process.

My first thought was try to return a `Future<Boolean>` instead of a regular `boolean`, but I am unsure as to how would I associate the result with the name that it was initially called with.

The reason why I want aMethod to run in parallel/asynchronous is because aMethod might have a http request. If there is a request, I do not want to wait for a reply to continue. I want it to do that in a separate thread and continue on to the next method.

With a lot of http requests, aClass.doMethod() takes a while to accomplish. I want to run them in parallel so I don't have to wait for each http request before continuing.

Anyone have tips on how to accomplish this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//Strategy.java
public interface Strategy {
    boolean aMethod();
}

//AStrategy.java
public class AStrategy implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public boolean aMethod() {
        // Do a couple http requests
        return true;
    }
}

//BStrategy.java
public class BStrategy implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public boolean aMethod() {
        // Do some other requests
        return true;
    }
}

//SomeClass.java
public class SomeClass {
    String name;
    Strategy aStrategy;

    public SomeClass(String name, Strategy strategy) {
        this.name = name;
        this.aStrategy = strategy;
    }

    public boolean doMethod() {
        return aStrategy.aMethod();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

//Just a regular pojo
//ResultsClass.java
public class ResultsClass {
    String name;
    boolean result;

    public ResultsClass(String name, boolean result) {
        this.name = name;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(boolean result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

public class AClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<SomeClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(new SomeClass("Class 1", new AStrategy()));
        classes.add(new SomeClass("Class 2", new BStrategy()));

        List<ResultsClass> results = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.forEach(aClass -> results.add(new ResultsClass(aClass.getName(), aClass.doMethod())));

    }
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are actually asking for. And your source code is **full** with invalid java syntax. You should seriously step back; and for example, start by putting down an example that compiles and runs; and shows the problem you intend to solve. And honestly: if you dont understand yet how to write a syntactically correct java program, forget about doing multi-threading for now. Learn to crawl before you try to run.

Comment: Sorry for the missing syntax... I was trying to recall what I was doing and was trying to multitask switching between writing up the question and something else. I have edited it so it compiles....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way for you to do this is probably to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, make your strategy classes runnable or wrap them in runnables, and submit them to the executor.  Once all are submitted, you can block on the futures until the threads complete and you can retrieve the results from the futures.